Safe init on the Browser
I am trying to initialize the safe SDK and I see I have to use an RPC URL
const protocolKitOwner1 = await Safe.init({
  provider: RPC_URL,
  signer: OWNER_1_PRIVATE_KEY,
  safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS
})

according to the docs
can I use the ethers browser provider instead
something like this
const browserProvider = ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
const signer_ = await provider.getSigner()
const protocolKitOwner1 = await Safe.init({
  provider: browserProvider,
  signer: signer_
  safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS
})




Yes, I think you should be able to use the browser provider as well. Are you facing any issues in doing so?
